# Howto run a Prestashop docker container with persistent data?

Tags: docker, prestashop, volume

There is something I'm missing in many docker examples and that is persistent data. Am I right if I conclude that every container that is stopped will lose it's data?

I got this Prestashop image running with it's internal database:
https://hub.docker.com/r/prestashop/prestashop/

You just run `docker run -ti --name some-prestashop -p 8080:80 -d prestashop/prestashop`

Well you got your demo then, but not very practical.
First of all I need to hook an external MySQL container, but that one will also lose all it's data if for example my server reboots.

And what about all the modules and themes that are going to be added to the prestashop container?

It has to do with Volumes, but it is not clear to my how all the the host volumes needs to be mapped correctly and what path to the host is normally chosen. /opt/prestashop er something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't have any experience with PrestaShop. This is an example which you can use for every docker container (from which you want to persist the data).
With the new version of docker (1.11) it's pretty easy to 'persist' your data.
First create your named volume:

```
docker volume create --name prestashop-volume
```

You will see this volume in `/var/lib/docker/volumes`:
prestashop-volume

After you've created your named volume container you can connect your container with the volume container:

```
docker run -ti --name some-prestashop -p 8080:80 -d -v prestashop-volume:/path/to/what/you/want/to/persist :prestashop/prestashop
```

*(when you really want to persist everything, I think you can use the path `:/` )*

Now you can do what you want on your database.
When your container goes down or you delete your container, the named volume will still be there and you're able to reconnect your container with the named-volume.

To make it even more easy you can create a cron-job which creates a .tar of the content of `/var/lib/docker/volumes/prestashop-volume/`
When really everything is gone you can restore your volume by recreating the named-volume and untar your .tar-file in it.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was easy :) The volumes inside the prestashop dockerfile are the locations which are exposed to the outside world?

Comment: I think those VOLUME xxx are mountpoints inside your container. Hope this can help you. section: VOLUME: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/